# Should I be concerned with the higher current draw coming from a part of my circuit design, and if so, how should I limit it in my circumstance?

Tags: operational-amplifier, current, simulation, current-limiting, vco

I'm designing a voltage controlled oscillator for a modular synthesizer. My planned range for this circuit is anywhere between 37Hz to ~20kHz. Here's a schematic of it I made with the [Falstad Simulator](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/):

---

[image: The Schematic]

---

In this configuration, with the resistance values I'm currently using, Op-Amp 2's output should produce a DC-offset saw wave with peaks at ±5% of ~5V.

The simulation shows a peak current of ~2.2mA at the junction between OpAmp 1's input, the capacitor, and the 1k resistor leading to the BJT's collector. While that should be within specs for everything in that area, it seems like way more than any of the other components need. (That's almost 30% of the 7mA being drawn by the whole circuit!)
I tried adding a resistor to correct this, but since that voltage is also being divided and utilized elsewhere in the circuit, the resistor affected the voltage the other components were receiving.

**Question:**
Should I be concerned with limiting that current, and if so, how should I do it? would a current regulator work in this circumstance?

**(Side Question**: In production, I'm planning on using multiple VCOs on a single board, so I've decided to use a TL074 quad op-amp, an LM393 dual comparator, and a BC847BS dual BJT chip for every two VCOs. I haven't yet simulated with these specific devices, but *by how much are the differences likely to alter the results of this first simulation?***)**

Comment: Where is your voltage control input? Is it what's labelled "-5V" into the 100K of the 1st opamp? What is its min and max?

Comment: @td127 that -5V source is a temporary voltage control I'm using to test the waveform output; eventually it will be transistor controlled. My planned range is ≤0V to -5V with the oscillator tuned tuned digitally to around 1V per octave. I haven't yet built the circuit with real parts, so different resistance values may need to be used to tune it closer to 1V/Oct. Eventually it will have computer controlled feedback to correct for frequency distortion as well. (The comparator outputs a pulse that can be timed by a microcontroller.)

Comment: Another question: is the "-5V" into the bottom 100K a fixed -5V or also connected to your input control voltage? By the way, the LM393 has an open collector output so won't work as you've drawn. It needs a pullup resistor, i.e. put the 20K to +12V and take the comparator output directly to the transistor base. The 20K will act as a current limit when transistor is on.

Comment: Last question, a clarification really: is it your desire that the final output be a sawtooth that goes from 0V to +5V and can be swept from 0.5Hz to 20kHz?

Comment: @td127 Good point! The pull-up resistor was in my first design, but it broke the simulation circuit. I'll add it back in when I move to physical parts. I should have been a little more specific when talking about range. I was planning on using this same circuit as an LFO oscillator as well, but separate from the tonal VCOs. My main goal is to at least have a total range of all notes from C1 to C8 (and beyond, so something like 37Hz to ~20kHz) with 5 of those 8 octaves being available to reach with CV without having to adjust a pitch gain switch.

Comment: Ha, my answer and your comment arrived simultaneously. Glad you're not aiming for the full 15 octaves in one circuit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that what you want is a sawtooth output that goes from 0V to +5V (has a 2.5V DC offset), then you don’t need the second opamp at all. The first opamp can generate that directly by just adjusting the comparator threshold to 2.5V.

[image]

The schematic has the correction needed to make an open collector like the LM339 work: when its output is low it will clamp firmly to 0V, but when it’s “high” it actually disconnects itself so an external pullup is needed to pull the line high. In this state the base current will be supplied from +12V through the 20K pullup.

As to your original concern about peak current levels, the ~2.2mA you saw in the simulation was probably just the quick discharge current of the cap, nothing to worry about. The capacitor charging current is much lower.

You are aiming for a 0.5Hz to 20kHz range which is 15 octaves! This is well beyond the capabilities of this simple circuit.

The oscillator portion of this circuit is the current through the 1nF capacitor producing a ramp from 0V up to twice the comparator threshold, at which point the comparator flips and resets the cap.

The formula for the ramp is:
I = C dv/dt

dv is the change in voltage over the ramp period, 5V

dt is the time of the ramp, at max 20kHz that is 50us

your C is 1nF

so the current I for 20kHz is = 1n * 5 / 50u = 100uA

And every octave lower is half the current.

20kHz -> 100uA

10kHz -> 50uA

5kHz -> 25uA

…

0.5Hz-> 3nA

3nA is on the order of the opamp offset current.
You can improve things by using 10nF – at least then the range is 30na to 1ma.

But you left out the hard part: how to convert 1V/octave to this wide exponential current range?
This is an extreme challenge beyond even most commercial products.
An audio-only oscillator (ten octaves, 20-20kHz) would be challenge enough.
Leave the sub 20Hz range to a separate LFO module I reckon.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help! Sorry for the confusion with the frequency range, too. :P

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the VCO design shown in the datasheet of the LM324 that can produce two VCOs?
[image: VCO]

Comment: I'll be honest, I haven't seen that design before. My design is based on a VCO a friend of mine made. There are a few problems I have with TI's design, though.

First off- and I don't know if this is simulation error or not- the waves aren't very stable, and the frequency cycles of both op-amps are out of sync.

Secondly, I also was wanting to include a sawtooth wave, as well as PWM and a autotune timer pulse. PWM might be possible with this one, but I don't think the saw and timer pulse are.

Comment: @PlugN'Play Falstad and even CircuitLab have lots of trouble simulating certain kinds of relatively circuits. CircuitLab is abandonware at this point it looks like, bugs remain untouched for years. It’s a tool for “experts” those who understand its quirks at this point. You’ll be way more productive with a breadboard to figure the details out, or using a better tool like LTspice or MicroCap (free now!).

Comment: Any high impedance circuit  is unstable when built with wires all over the place on a solderless breadboard. The second opamp is an inverter.